# Something is not Right in Rightster

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs, advertising

Earlier today I noticed this Careers ad:

> [image]

The squared circled "r" is utterly mispositioned.

Quick digging into the HTML showed the background to be [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uOSwm.png), which is correct, but I could not find the source of the misbehaving "r".

I assume this is a failed attempt to mimic the behavior in the [company page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/rightster):

> [image]

Can this please be fixed, likely by just removing the [image]?

Comment: I'm confused what the issue is. That's [how it's supposed to be](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3LcfO.png), they just picked a non-ideal background image.

Comment: @Tim so they always put the company name on the logo? Didn't really notice, but this one just looks bad.

Comment: Yeah, I wonder if companies are shown samples of the ad creatives when they upload these images...might help prevent this kind of scenario

Comment: Also, the dumbbell/weights are shown next to the beer fridge instead of the onsite gym.